# How to post data as stream with httpclient in .net core?

Tags: .net-core, httpclient, httpwebrequest

Here is my scenario:
User speaks continuously to a microphone on client side, and the client code need post the recorded audio data to server chunk by chunk, though HTTP protocol.
Server side can receive and process the audio data chunk by chunk.
The question is about the code on client side.

Previously using dotnet framework I can implement the posting as stream (chunks) with below code:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.sendchunked?view=netframework-4.8#examples

But it doesn't work after switching to dotnet core, which is a known issue mentioned here:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18632#issuecomment-470611032

I saw httpclient was recommended by above thread.
But I didn't find out any sample code for my scenario using httpclient.
For my scenario I need get connected to the server, and then get an input stream based on this connection, and then write my recorded audio from microphone to server chunk by chunk through this stream.

This can be done by using the sample code in [above link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.sendchunked?view=netframework-4.8#examples).

How should I write the code to implement the same effect using httpclient?